# May the Beginning and the End of Eternal Time be with You

Tags: riddle, wordplay, rhyme, animals

I am:

> The beginning of the outsider, the omitted, the omega,
>
> and also of the most-able, the marking, the mega.
>
> The middle of the vision, the view, the vector,
>
> and also of the ribs, the river, and the runner.
>
> The end of the pain, the powerful, and the primate,
>
> and also of the witty, the weary, and the white.

What am I?

Criteria:

> green tick: find "I" and all words-to-be-found
>
> additional +1: all words-to-be-found in a line begins with same letter

Hint:

> vision: ( (o)
> vector: #include  
> runner: [animals](/questions/tagged/animals)
> powerful: definition--> with capability
> witty: [animals](/questions/tagged/animals) + so near, yet so far... ;) **READ RIDDLE AGAIN**

Enjoy!

Comment: Something do do with Rot13: svaqvat flabalzf jurer gur vaqvpngrq yrggre zngpurf va nyy guerr jbeqf?

Comment: on the right track rot13(svaqvat flabalzf bs rnpu jbeq, svaq gur pbzzba cneg)

Comment: So...we are supposed to rot13(trg n yrggre sebz rnpu bs gur guerr jbeqf va n yvar, erfhygvat va guerr yrggref cre yvar)?

Comment: r13(guerr jbeqf cre yvar, jvgu fnzr cneg ng fnzr cbfvgvba (svther jung vg zrnaf ol cbfvgvba lbhefrys ;) ), nyy jbeqf unir gung cneg, va qvssrerag cbfvgvbaf. svaq gur cneg)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is it

> The letter 'e'

Beginning of:

> outsider=>**e**migrant, omitted=>**e**rased, omega=>**e**nd(omega is the last letter of the greek alphabet), most-able=> **e**minent, marking=>**e**valuating, mega=>**e**normous

Middle of:

> vision=>dr**e**am, view=>sc**e**ne, vector=> persp**e**ctive, ribs=> ch**e**st, river=> cr**e**ek, runner=>mess**e**nger

End of:

> pain=>ach**e**, powerful=> suprem**e**, primat**e**(or chimpanze**e**), witty=>jocos**e**, weary=>pron**e**, white=>pal**e**

The title:

> The beginning and the end of **E**ternal Tim**e**

Comment: better now, check out hint, and try aiming for the +1!

Answer (score 1):

Original answer to remaining words:

vision:

> see

vector:

> set

witty:

> primate

Comment: why is 'witty' primate?

Comment: a bit of a stretch, but i think primates are the most witty animals?

Comment: well, you could have asked for pancake, pole or some others, but to get 'primate' from witty seems a bit difficult.

Comment: true, i'll try my best to do better next time, thanks for your reflection!

Answer (score 0):

Using Omega Krypton's hints, and cppcodor's lead, I think some more of the answers are:

runner

> che**e**tah (with chest and creek)

pain, powerful, primate

> ache, **a**ble, **a**pe

witty (and be warned, this one is pretty funny!)

> partridg**e**, as in [Alan Partridge](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alan_Partridge), (so with prone and pale)

Comment: well done, all correct except the last one... i'll add a hint